# How to modify an object in webflow through ajax?

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I'm having trouble understanding how ajax, a controller, and web-flow can interact.

As of right now, my project moves from page to page from different view states through the flow.

However, on some of these different pages, I have a few ajax calls that get directed to various controllers for server processing on a "currentObject". The services return an object, which I need to put back into the web-flow as my "currentObject".

Just to make things clear: I want to associate object A with object B, which object A is associated to the "currentObject". I do my server processing and complete the association(so "currentObject" is associated to object A which is associated to object B) and save the object to database. When I click on "create new object", web-flow still has the "currentObject" where object A is NOT associated with object B.

I want to put my updated "currentObject" into web-flow from my controller, so what is the best approach to modifying the object in web-flow through an ajax call?

Adam

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a tricky one. I was in a similar situation and found this post to be helpful: [Ajax + Spring Webflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603177/ajax-spring-webflow)

The basic problem is that the object in your webflow is serialized, so just doing an AJAX call and then modifying something in the DB as you would do with a normal controller won't work.

In my case, the basic model object is "plan" and I wanted to drop a child object called "task." I set up a transition in my webflow's XML config as follows:

```
<transition on="dropTask">
    <evaluate expression="planService.dropTaskFromPlan(requestParameters.taskID,  plan)" />
</transition>
```

The class "planService" will run through my "Plan" object, find the task with the given ID, and remove it.

Here's the ajax call:

```
var targetUrl = $("#actionPlanForm").attr("action") +     '&_eventId_dropTask=_eventId_dropTask';
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    data: $("#actionPlanForm").serialize() + '&taskID=' + taskID,
    url : targetUrl
});
```