# Ajax call to WebFlow with tiles

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-webflow, tiles

I am following your example "Ajax call to WebFlow" but i am not get it to working.
Could you please share your example.My problem is that i want to make an ajax call from a page and get some part of it rendered but what i get from success function is the whole page content.

Here is what i have.

this is in my **xxx-flow.xml**

```
    <on-entry>
        <evaluate
            expression="requirementService.getRequirementDetailsForEdit(flowRequestContext)"
            result="flowScope.editableRequirement" />
    </on-entry>
    <transition on="addEmptySkillRequirements">
        <evaluate expression="requirementService.addEmptySkillRequirementForEdit(flowRequestContext)" 
        result="flowScope.content123"/>
    </transition>

    <transition on="continue" to="listRequirements" />
</view-state>
```

**This is my *.jsp call**

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=addEmptySkillRequirements&ajaxSource=true&fragments=content">
     <input type="submit" value="Insert111" name="_eventId_addEmptySkillRequirements" id="submitMyForm" onclick="insertData12()"/>
</form>
```

**In the same jsp, this is my ajax call**

```
function insertData12() {

    $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : '${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=addEmptySkillRequirements&ajaxSource=true&fragments=content',
                data : $("#myForm").serialize(),
                dataType: "text",
                accepts: "text/html",


                success : function(content) {
                    alert("success" + content);
                     $('#content').html(content);

                },
                error : function(data) {
                    alert('fail' );

                }
            });
    return false;
};
```

**This is my tiles.xml**

```
<definition name="editRequirement" extends="base.definition">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Requirement List" />
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/pages/requirements/editReqDetails.jsp"  />
</definition>
```

Comment: Which/Who's example are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

if you want only the fragment "content" to be rendered you have to put 

`<render fragments="content"/>` in your flow definition:

```
<transition on="addEmptySkillRequirements">
    <evaluate expression="requirementService.addEmptySkillRequirementForEdit(flowRequestContext)" 
    result="flowScope.content123"/>
    <render fragments="content"/>
</transition>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're still facing an issueUse &ajaxSource=insert_data, where 'insert_data' is id for your button. Please see my updated post for details:

[Ajax call to WebFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052106/ajax-call-to-webflow?rq=1)