# Ajax response from spring webflow

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-webflow

After ajax call I get response that contains whole jsp page. How can I get only part of page or when I use SWF how can I get only result from evaluate block ?
I have next ajax call in my js file:

```
var url = $('#srcCurrencySpace').attr('resource');
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : url,
        cache:false,
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        dataType: "text",
        success : function(response)
        {
            //Write you success logic here
            var newHtml = $('#srcCurrencySpace', response).html();
            $('#srcCurrencySpace').html(newHtml);
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            //Write you error-handling logic here
            alert("error!");
        }
      });
```

And this request go to:

```
<transition on="updateAmountSrcCurrency"  validate="false">
            <evaluate expression="retrieverFactory.getSrcCurrency(application)" result="flowScope.amountSrcCurrency"/>
            <render fragments="srcCurrencySpace"></render>
</transition>
```

And finally snippet from my jsp:

```
<span id="srcCurrencySpace" resource="${updateURL}">
            <c:out value="${amountSrcCurrency}" default="LVL" />
</span>
```

Comment: No, I do not used tiles (you mean  <beans:bean class="org.springframework.js.ajax.AjaxUrlBasedViewResolver">
   <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles2.AjaxTilesView"/>
</beans:bean>)

Comment: how do oyu trigger the transition? i can't see it in your ajax call

Comment: This is a related question about how to trigger the AJAX call to spring webflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603177/ajax-spring-webflow